# Can you use the 'action' attribute for a 'div' element?

Tags: html, frontend

My question is quite straight forward and simple. I am learning node JS and I know that the 'form' element has a 'action' attribute. I just want to know if even a div element has such an attribute...

Comment: [Form element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).  [Div element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, action attribute only works for form tag.
If you want to perform same as action does in form, you can use `<a href="https://www.websiteurl.com">Wrap div with this</a>`.
If you want to pass dynamic values like form you can provide in `herf` followed by `url/?id=5`.
You can also do it by using javascript by providing id to div

```
onClick="location.href='url-here'"
```